# Flutter runner exhausting system memory

Tags: flutter

When i run my flutter application. Its runs successfully but when i perform button click or touch screen `simulator/real device` hangs and when i check the runner process it is taking allot of memory and memory usage increases and crashed the runner process. I tried the following commands

```
 flutter clean && flutter pub get
 rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/CachedData/*
 rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Cache/*
```

I `restarted` my system. `Shutdown` the system completely and then start but nothing seems to work. When i run the application again i am getting same issue. It is appearing on both real device and simulator and  on `ios/android.`
`flutter doctor -v` shows all green which mean everything is okay.